# How to unpack nested json as it comes from the api into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am making a API GET request and getting back a unicode json response. I can read in the response into a dataframe but one column is getting nested. Is there anyway to unnest this column as I load it into a dataframe?

Code so far:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 123',
}

r = requests.get('url', headers=headers)

df = pd.read_json(r.text)
```

The column that is nested has that data that looks like this:

```
df.nested_data
{u'landing_id': u'xxx', u'landed_at': u'2018-10-03T17:44:33Z', u'answers': [{u'field': {u'type': u'picture_choice', u'ref': xxx, u'id': u'xxx'}, u'type': u'choice', u'choice': {u'label': u'gum'}}, {u'field': {u'type': u'picture_choice', u'ref': u'xxx, u'id': u'xxxx'}, u'type': u'choice', u'choice': {u'label': u'Great'}}, {u'field': {u'type': u'picture_choice', u'ref': u'xxxx', u'id': u'xxx'}, u'type': u'choice', u'choice': {u'label': u'Cool as ice'}}], u'token': u'xxx7d', u'submitted_at': u'2018-10-03T17:45:59Z', u'metadata': {u'network_id': u'axxx', u'platform': u'mobile', u'referer': u'xxx', u'user_agent': u'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; MHA-L29 Build/xxx-L29) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Mobile Safari/537.36', u'browser': u'touch'}}
```

How do I unnest this column so that it unpacks row wise?

Thankyou in advnace.

Comment: Please use `df = pd.read_json(r.json())` instead. Or, `df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(r.json())`

Comment: @coldspeed `df = pd.read_json(r.json())` gave me error `ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <type 'dict'>`

`df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(r.json())` truncated all records into one row without even flattening